# System.Web.UI.ViewStateException ,Invalid viewstate

Tags: asp.net, exception, viewstate

My website is throwing the below exceptions everyday and i couldn't find the solution.
i did few research in web and this is what i do so far. adding below option to aspx won't solve the problem.

> ValidateRequest="false" EnableEventValidation="false"
>   ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewStateMac="false"

Also, my Referral Url is the correct URL and i have no idea how it redirect with two (same) parameters. there is no such link in my referral page. Please help.

ERROR LOG

```
URL : http://www.abcd.com/company-details.aspx?com=asia-pacific-pte-ltd&com=asia-pacific-pte-ltd

referral URL : http://www.abcd.com/companies/asia-pacific-pte-ltd/

Inner Exception Type: System.Web.UI.ViewStateException

Inner Exception: Invalid viewstate. Client IP: 192.162.19.193 Port: 1966 User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; MRA 6.0 (build 6001)) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.11 ViewState: 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...

Inner Source: 

Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException

Exception: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Stack Trace: at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.exhibition_details_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0f461847\442b0502\App_Web_bfjqxdef.20.cs:line 0 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**UPDATE**
i have fixed the error by compressing the ViewState from below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression

and fixed the  Invalid length for a Base-64 char array error by replacing the original method with this.

```
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        string viewState = Request.Form["__VSTATE"];
        viewState = viewState.Replace(" ", "+");

        int mod4 = viewState.Length % 4;
        if (mod4 > 0)
        {
            viewState += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
        }
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(viewState);
        bytes = Compressor.Decompress(bytes);
        LosFormatter formatter = new LosFormatter();
        return formatter.Deserialize(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
```

Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sorry that say that but **your site did not have anything worng**, and you need to re-enable your EventValidations as soon as possible.

What you see is [an attempt to hack your site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround) by sending many test [numbers with your ViewState trying to find your hash key](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yghiC_U2RaM).

The [IP you give have a big list of activity the last few days](http://stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/192.162.19.193).

Now, alternative what may cause this error is the breaking of the ViewState. You can [compress it and split it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877252/limiting-view-state-information-on-ajax-calls/8964708#8964708) if you have too big ViewState. You can also [disable all the controls that not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086120/how-i-can-deactivate-viewstate-without-control-problems/12086277#12086277). Also you can add a [log to see from inside what's is going on right on a base page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551810/159270).

Comment: I removed these EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewStateMac="false" and compressed it from the link you gave me and it solved the problem. thank you very much :)

Comment: i am getting this errors now though, Invalid length for a Base-64 char array. help

Comment: @user597729 If you see it on the log only, check the IP, as I say you its probably a hack try and you do not need to worry. If you see it as user... then maybe its an issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes it works for me too

here in vbnet

Compressor.vb

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Public Class Compressor

Public Shared Function Compress(ByVal data() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim output As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Dim gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, True)
    gzip.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    gzip.Close()
    Return output.ToArray
End Function

Public Shared Function Decompress(ByVal data() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim input As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    input.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    input.Position = 0
    Dim gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress, True)
    Dim output As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Dim buff() As Byte = New Byte((64) - 1) {}
    Dim read As Integer = -1
    read = gzip.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)

    While (read > 0)
        output.Write(buff, 0, read)
        read = gzip.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)

    End While

    gzip.Close()
    Return output.ToArray
 End Function
End Class
```

and this you paste inside default.aspx
it needs

Imports System.IO

```
  Protected Overrides Function LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() As Object
    Dim viewState As String = Request.Form("__VSTATE")
    Dim bytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(viewState)
    bytes = Compressor.Decompress(bytes)
    Dim formatter As LosFormatter = New LosFormatter
    Return formatter.Deserialize(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes))
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(ByVal viewState As Object)
    Dim formatter As LosFormatter = New LosFormatter
    Dim writer As StringWriter = New StringWriter
    formatter.Serialize(writer, viewState)
    Dim viewStateString As String = writer.ToString
    Dim bytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(viewStateString)
    bytes = Compressor.Compress(bytes)
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__VSTATE", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes))
End Sub
```